# Toolbar Column Menu in Kendo Grid using AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to use the Kendo ui-Menu in the toolbar of the Kendo Grid like below:
[image]
I was able to get this to work using JQuery (here's a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0ebo57p8/), but I need to get it to work in Angular.

I tried using this in the datababound function of the grid:

```
              for (var i = 0, max = $scope.SearchGrid.columns.length; i < max; i++) {
              ds.push({
                  encoded: false,
                  text: "<label><input type='checkbox' checked='checked' " +
                      " class='check' data-field='" +
                      $scope.SearchGrid.columns[i].field +
                      "</label>"
              });

          }
```

Then this in the controller:

```
 $scope.menuDataSource = [
{
    text: "Edit Columns",
    items: ds

}];
```

I have it in the toolbar like this:

```
toolbar: [

          {
              name: "Edit Columns",
              template:
                  '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="k-button btn btn-default btn-xs" style="float: left" kendo-menu k-data-source="menuDataSource"></div>'
          }
      ],
```

but the menu renders before there is anything in "ds" and I can't figure out how to call something like a `dataSource.read()` on Menu.  I figure there must be a way to do this, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to set items in your kendoMenu after grid renders but kendoMenu is used in grid toolbar. The best solution would be set new items in menu dataSource after grid read it's data. You can use dataSource `setOptions` method of `kendoMenu` eg.:

```
$('div[kendo-grid="SearchGrid"] .k-menu').data('kendoMenu').setOptions({dataSource: $scope.menuDataSource});
```

Check this example - i add Item2 to dataSource and I set in in kendoMenu: http://dojo.telerik.com/OnAXI/2

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately, this is not working for me.  Here is a Dojo - http://dojo.telerik.com/@DevQueen/owIHEh.  I am trying to produce the menu dynamically with the column names from the grid.  I tried calling a function on databound, but I get nothing.

Comment: You were very close. Here it works: http://dojo.telerik.com/uwUSa. `dataBound` is case sensitive, `ds` is not required here, I fixed template and you need to use `length` property of array in for instruction to get number of elements.